# In Vue js Image can't find from Node Js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I have run my Nodejs server in 3000 port and Vuejs 8080 port. Now I can get data from "posts" collection via API but when a want to access image it can't find the image.

My Error is :GET http://localhost:3000/images/1656300140014picture.PNG 404 (Not Found)

```
               <tbody>
                  <tr v-for="(item, index) in getAllPost" :key="item._id">
                    <td>{{ index + 1 }}</td>
                    <td>
                      
                      <img
                        :src="
                          'http://localhost:3000/images/' + item.postImage
                        "
                        style="width: 50px"
                      />

                    </td>
                    <td v-if="item.author">{{ item.author.userName }}</td>
                    <td v-if="item.author == null">N/A</td>
                    <td>{{ item.title }}</td>

                    <td class="text-right">
                      <router-link
                        :to="{ name: 'mainLayout' }"
                        class="btn btn-primary mr-2"
                      >
                        <i class="fas fa-eye"></i>
                      </router-link>
                      <button class="btn btn-primary mr-2">
                        <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                      </button>
                      <button class="btn btn-danger mr-2">
                        <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
                      </button>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEs2i.png)

Comment: If in your public folder, the Image might be server from same port as your frontend, 8080.  Try with '/images/...' URL, or even port 8080.

Comment: Sir, My image stored in my Node project file and I want to access the image in another vue js project file.

Comment: Try to open the image directly in the browser. If it still has a 404 error, then your node server doesn't find the image under that URL. Maybe the URL path is wrong. Can you provide more info about your project? Can you show us your folder structure? What function / controller returns the image?  Based on your image, I cannot see the a images path. I only see the name of the image.